# HyperLedger Fabric Network Setup

Tags: networking, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

Whenever I build network  I get this error Can anyone explain the reason?

```
transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 172.22.0.9:7051: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {peer0.org1.example.com:7051}
```

[I have extended basic network code for more peers & organizations 
Fabric-samples V1.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgBuB.png)

Comment: Please add 1) your platform (windows/linux etc) 2) Fabric version 3) which network are you trying to create 4) at what stage you get the error etc. This will help others to better understand the context.

Comment: Ubuntu , Fabric v1.0.0,basic network-solo ordering,image attached for error stage

Comment: Sorry i am new here aint familiar with the ways :/

Comment: Thats fine, please edit your question and add the info there. Also, I would recommend version 1.3, 1.00 is pretty old now.

Comment: I have edited and added a pic showing the error and i am using basic network code its Version hasn't been updated. The chaincode has been updated i guess